# How to determine if a value of a key exist in my settings vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have start to develop a new application to generate md5 hashes from strings and the it save automatic to my.settings.md5_hashes 
and now i need to check if a certain value all ready exist in my settings md5_hashes. i have find some examples but it give me all ways a error on it
the error 
Error   1   Value of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'.
how can i check if a value its all ready exist on my settings?

This is my code

```
Public Class Form3



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If My.Settings.md5_hashes = (TextBox1.Text) Then

    End If

    If Not My.Settings.md5_hashes = (TextBox1.Text) Then
        Me.Show()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code to generate the hashes and save it to my.settings.md5_hashes

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Settings.md5_hashes.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim md5 As MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
    Dim inputBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim hash As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        sb.Append(hash(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text + "<--->" + TextBox2.Text)

    My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(TextBox1.Text + "<--->" + TextBox2.Text)

    My.Settings.Save()





End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each item In My.Settings.md5_hashes
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim i As Integer
    W = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\MD5.txt", True)

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    W.Close()
    MsgBox("You File Is Save You Can Locate It At C:\MD5.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Form3.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

well i have just change some part of the code 
this is my new code

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'My.Settings.md5_hashes.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim md5 As MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
    Dim inputBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim hash As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        sb.Append(hash(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)

    My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    My.Settings.md5_hashes.Add("<--->")

    My.Settings.Save()





End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each item In My.Settings.md5_hashes
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim i As Integer
    W = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\MD5.txt", True)

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    W.Close()
    MsgBox("You File Is Save You Can Locate It At C:\MD5.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Form3.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

well now its return true but how can i get the value to show on a msgbox the results?
well i solved my self the way to get results of the name for example if i search with the name to retrieved the hash , but how to do if i search for a hash and get the name how to take the name i stored initial there ?

Comment: The the application insert on a listbox the string and on the bottom the hash for example anne and on the bottom of it the hash e3fb62ebfa4f36acf5cbff6a6ed0f2e0

Comment: This line in `Form1_Load` is part of your problem: `My.Settings.md5_hashes.Clear()` - it removes all the saved hashes when you start the application.

Comment: But I see now that you also store the hashes along with the original input, why is that?

Comment: You are creating a hash for each character instead of string.  Try this : string.Join("", hash.Select(function(x) x.ToString("x2")).  So the code will create a string like : "0E0F124567".

Comment: @jdweng : No, he's _converting each byte to HEX_, but he's still hashing the whole string. His code is taken from an example of the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng : If I'm not mistaken calculating the HEX for each byte is the correct way of doing it. The string you got is way too short.

Comment: @visual vicent i store with the original name to compare wen i am search for it

Comment: ok i could do in different way for example get the strinf again of it and compare if that hahashes exist

Comment: Our discussion has been moved to chat by a moderator. The only problem with that is that you don't get notified of new messages, just so you know. Link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145815/discussion-on-answer-by-visual-vincent-how-to-determine-if-a-value-of-a-key-exis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**`Contains` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
If My.Settings.md5_hashes.Contains(TextBox1.Text) = True Then
    'Hash exists, do something.
Else
    'Hash does not exist, do something else.
End If
```

**Tip:** Check what members IntelliSense shows you when you type `My.Settings.md5_hashes.` (notice the dot on the end). By doing so you would most likely have found the answer to this yourself.

---

**EDIT:**

In your specific case it gets a little more complicated because you must separate the input and the hash before you can check that the hash exists.

Try this (this is for the first code you posted in the question):

```
Private Function HashExists(ByVal Hash As String) As Boolean
    For Each Entry As String In My.Settings.md5_hashes 'Iterate through every hash entry.
        Dim Parts As String() = Entry.Split(New String() {"<--->"}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'Split the entry on "<--->".
        If Parts.Length = 1 AndAlso Parts(0) = Hash Then
            Return True 'No "<--->" was present, but the entire entry matches 'Hash'.
        ElseIf Parts.Length >= 2 AndAlso Parts(1) = Hash
            Return True 'The entry was split successfully and the second part and 'Hash' are equal.
        End If
    Next
    Return False 'No valid hash found.
End Function
```

Then use this like:

```
If HashExists(TextBox1.Text) = True Then
    'Hash exists, do something.
Else
    'Hash does not exist, do something else.
End If
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

To get the name from a hash or a hash from a name the above code just need to be modified slightly to return any of the two parts.

```
Private Function GetEntry(ByVal Input As String, ByVal NameFromHash As Boolean) As String
    For Each Entry As String In My.Settings.md5_hashes 'Iterate through every hash entry.
        'Parts(0) is the name.
        'Parts(1) is the hash.
        Dim Parts As String() = Entry.Split(New String() {"<--->"}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'Split the entry on "<--->".
        If Parts.Length >= 2 Then
            If NameFromHash = True AndAlso Parts(1) = Input Then
                Return Parts(0) 'Input was a valid hash, return name.
            ElseIf NameFromHash = False AndAlso Parts(0) = Input Then
                Return Parts(1) 'Input was a valid name, return hash.
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing 'No valid entry found.
End Function
```

Usage:

```
'Get the name from a hash.
Dim Name As String = GetEntry(TextBox1.Text, True)

'Get the hash from a name.
Dim Hash As String = GetEntry(TextBox1.Text, False)
```

If the function returns `Nothing` that means it couldn't find the name/hash you specified. To avoid getting a `NullReferenceException` you can check so in an `If`-statement:

```
'Name from hash.
If Name IsNot Nothing Then
    'The specified hash was found, do something with the name.
Else
    'Hash not found.
    MessageBox.Show("The specified hash was not found.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If


'Hash from name.
If Hash IsNot Nothing Then
    'The specified name was found, do something with the hash.
Else
    'Name not found.
    MessageBox.Show("The specified name was not found.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145815/discussion-on-answer-by-visual-vincent-how-to-determine-if-a-value-of-a-key-exis).